# Combining arrays of objects that are linked

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have 3 arrays of objects. They look like this:

- `$arr1`, `$arr2`  :  Objects with properties like (`ID`, `filename`, `size`, etc).
- `$arrlink` : Objects with properties like (`file1ID`, `file2ID`, misc). This links 2 of the above objects

What I need to do is combine them into one array so I can write it to a CSV.  The 3 need to be linked: `File1ID` and `File2ID` to the `ID` column in the other 2 arrays.  I need to be able to pick what properties I want.  Here's an example

```
$arr1[0] = {1,"c:\filename1.txt",1000....}
$arr1[1] = {2,"c:\filename2.txt",2000....}

$arrlink[0] = {1,2,"aaaa")
```

Desired Result:

```
newarray[0] = {"c:\filename1.txt", "c:\filename2.txt", "aaaa"}
```

I know I can foreach through and do this, but was wondering if there was a simpler/more direct way.

Of course, there are many items in each array, but they all link up in a 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: Convert the arrays(with objects) to a hashtable with fileID as key. Then foreach your link-array and use the id's in the "link object" to extract the values you need from the hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using this. It saves a lot of typing and doesn't need to be modified if I modify the underlying objects (as long as I leave the linked fields alone).

```
$arrOutput = @()

foreach($a in $arrMatch)
    {
    $objOut = New-Object PsObject

    $a.psobject.properties | % { $objOut | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value}
    $arrS1[$a.file1].psobject.properties | % { $objOut | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name ($_.Name + "_1")  -Value $_.Value}
    $arrS2[$a.file2].psobject.properties | % { $objOut | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name ($_.Name + "_2") -Value $_.Value}
    $arrOutput+= $objOut
    }
```